# Introducing functional paradigm in Prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

So as the title suggests, what I want to do is already sounding bad, I admit. But I need this for reasons beyond my control.

Say I do this:

```
nb_setval(myvar, 10).
```

Can I access `myvar` anywhere in a rule as follows:

```
$myvar * 2
```

This would avoid having to do:

```
nb_getval(myvar, MYVAR), ...., MYVAR * 2
```

I suspect this isn't possible.

Comment: You can likely do it using the term- and goal-expansion mechanisms in order to expand goals such as `$myvar * 2` into `nb_getval(myvar, MYVAR), ...., MYVAR * 2`.

Comment: What I need is for prolog to see 10 wherever it sees $myvar. Not sure if that can be done using expansion.

Comment: `?- pack_install(func).`

Comment: As a beginner, do not use `nb_setval/2` and related predicates.

Comment: What about making the assignment context explicit? Pass a list [myvar-10, othervar-5] as an additional argument to the function evaluation predicate. Then even assignment is possible by modifying the context.

Comment: @lambda.xy.x This still falls within the logic/instantiation/unification paradigm, so offers the same problems.

Comment: @false why? Also, I'm not a beginner.

Comment: @CapelliC This looks like what I need :) Will look more into it.

Comment: If you take care that all arguments are ground and you cut after entering a rule, you should have a functional language.